# Multilingual enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net mvc web site Localization and I've faced problems with enums translation.

I need code like this:

```
public enum PossibilityEnum
{
   [LocalDescription(CultureCode=UserLoginInfo.UserLang, ResourceKey="ProjectDelete")]
   ProjectDelete,
   [LocalDescription(CultureCode=UserLoginInfo.UserLang, ResourceKey="ProjectCreate")]
   ProjectCreate,
   [LocalDescription(CultureCode=UserLoginInfo.UserLang, ResourceKey="ProjectEdit")]
   ProjectEdit
}
```

UserLoginInfo is my custom class, where I have all info about user.

Is it possible? And how can I make it?

***Edit***
UserLoginInfo has property

```
public LangType UserLang { get { return LangType.Eng; } }

public enum LangType
    {
        [Tag(TagType.Culture, "ru-RU")]
        Rus = 1,
        [Tag(TagType.Culture, "en")]
        Eng = 2,
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to have different labels for the enum values depending on the locale?

Comment: Your way of decorating your enum might be sub optimal. Take a look at this article: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/.

Comment: Yes I have kind of task with different labels for enum values, but values depends on information in user account, not location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that your View is just a means of presenting data to your user.

Although the enum is used within the code, you shouldn't be using a parsed version of your enum as text on your View. Instead use it to select a string resource, which can easily be translated.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but my problem rather lays in parsing all enums in my project. And I have a lot of it.

Comment: Parse them to get the resource string from your resourse files. This code would go in the property value that your using to provide data to your View. Just that it would be a string rather than an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a method in a class like this

```
public static string GetLocalizedName(Enum enumeration){
    System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] mi = enumeration.GetType().GetMember(enumeration.ToString());
    LocalDescription ld =  (LocalDescription) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(mi[0], typeof(LocalDescription), false);
    if (null != ld)
    return getfromresource(ld.CultureCode, ld.ResourceKey);
}
```

getfromresource is pseudo method, implementation is up to you.

Definition of "LocalDescription" can be like below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class LocalDescription : Attribute
{
    public LocalDescription (string cc, string rk)
    {
        CultureCode = cc;
        ResourceKey = rk;
    }
    public string CultureCode{get;set;}
    public string ResourceKEy{get;set;}

}
```